# Multiple Updates for Multiple String Values Using CASE WHEN and LIKE?

Tags: sql

I am attempting to update several values in a table based on several conditions. If a column (let's call it "name") contains some set of strings, I would like to change the name to something else. For example, if name contains two consecutive a's, like "aa", I would like to change it to just "A".

Here is my query that is currently not working:

```
UPDATE table
   SET name = CASE name 
                      WHEN name like "%aa%" then "A" 
                      WHEN name like "%er%" then "E"
                      ELSE "Z"
                      END
 WHERE name is not null
```

I know it is a non-sensical example, but I'm not great with coming up with those on the spot. The error I am currently getting is:

> "*No matching signature for operator CASE for argument types: STRING, BOOL, STRING, BOOL, STRING, STRING at [2:18]*.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.  The antecedent of "it" in the last sentence of the first paragraph is unclear.

Comment: Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes generally aren't used in SQL, but that can vary from database to database.

Stick to using single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `name` from `CASE name` and replace double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`:

```
UPDATE table
   SET name = CASE 
                      WHEN name like '%aa%' then 'A' 
                      WHEN name like '%er%' then 'E'
                      ELSE 'Z'
                      END
 WHERE name is not null
```

P.S. in this example and your question query the word table is the name of the table not the keyword table. That means that in some databases you will have problems and you will have to put this word in quotes.

[In this DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a19c8ddd90e1666915d1407e804df536) you can see that the query from my answer will work in **MySQL** database when you put word table in quotes.

[In this DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b8277328c924c9be630860d01518bfd) you can see that the query from my answer will work in **Oracle** database when you put word table in double quotes. Also you will see that the strings(values of columns) can not be between double quotes in Oracle.

**Note**: Some of the databases will not cause errors if the string(column value) is between double quotes but it is better to use single quotes for this and because you have not tagged a database that you use this are some guidelines that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `name` in the `CASE` clause:

```
UPDATE table
   SET name = CASE WHEN name like "%aa%" then "A" 
                   WHEN name like "%er%" then "E"
                   ELSE "Z"
                   END
 WHERE name is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what The Impaler said,remove the first `name` in the `CASE` clause. SQL syntax does not call for the column name directly after case. For example (From W3 schools):

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first instance of the word name

```
UPDATE table
   SET name = CASE 
                      WHEN name like "%aa%" then "A" 
                      WHEN name like "%er%" then "E"
                      ELSE "Z"
                      END
 WHERE name is not null
```

There are two ways to use case:

1)    CASE WHEN name=1 THEN WHEN name=2 THEN...

2)    CASE name WHEN 1 THEN WHEN 2 THEN...

In the first case it looks for the first TRUE expression, in the second for the first expression that is equal to name.
You made a mix of the two, but for the interpreter it is the second form.
Therefore, it was looking for the first expression equal to name. When it reads the first WHEN, it checks whether name is equal to the argument (name like "%aa%")
But (name like "%aa%") is a boolean, name is a string, hence the error.